# display greeting according to current time in appendChild()

Tags: javascript, variables, appendchild

I created a h3 within a div and now am trying to display a greeting appropriate for the current time of day. It displays on the play as an h3 but only results in undefined.

Can someone tell me what I am missing or doing wrong that the hours will not calculate?

```js
var h3 = document.createElement("h3");
var d = new Date();
var hour = d.getHours();
var greeting;


function greetCustomer() {
 if (hour > 18) {
   greeting = "Good Evening";
 }
  
 else if (hour > 12) {
   greeting = "Good Afternoon";
 }
  
 else if (hour > 5) {
   greeting = "Good Morning";
 }
  
 else {
   greeting = "Welcome Night Owl";
 } 
  
  document.getElementById("greeting").appendChild(h3);
}

h3.innerHTML = greetCustomer();
```

```html
<div id="greeting"></div>
```

Comment: Just `return` the text you want from the greetCustomer() function if you're just assigning it to a element's `innerHTML`

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do that? I am a student still currently learning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the greeting string from the function.

You don't need to append the H3 to the DOM in `greetCustomer()`, that should be done outside the function. And all the time-related variables should be local to the function, since they need to be recomputed every time the function is used.

```js
var h3 = document.createElement("h3");
document.getElementById("greeting").appendChild(h3);
h3.innerHTML = greetCustomer();

function greetCustomer() {
  var d = new Date();
  var hour = d.getHours();
  var greeting;
  if (hour > 18) {
    greeting = "Good Evening";
  } else if (hour > 12) {
    greeting = "Good Afternoon";
  } else if (hour > 5) {
    greeting = "Good Morning";
  } else {
    greeting = "Welcome Night Owl";
  }
  return greeting;
}
```

```html
<div id="greeting"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much!! This is exactly what I needed. I appreciate you help!!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't returning anything from your function; that will solve your problem.

On a different note, you should be using [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerHTML) instead of `innerHTML`. And you should probably append `h3` outside of your `greetCustomer()` function.

```js
function greetCustomer() {
  var d = new Date();
  var hour = d.getHours();
  var greeting;

  if (hour > 18) {
    greeting = "Good Evening";
  } else if (hour > 12) {
    greeting = "Good Afternoon";
  } else if (hour > 5) {
    greeting = "Good Morning";
  } else {
    greeting = "Welcome Night Owl";
  }

  return greeting;
}

var h3 = document.createElement("h3");
h3.textContent = greetCustomer();
document.querySelector('#greeting').appendChild(h3);
```

```html
<div id="greeting"></div>
```